# Passbook / Wallet pkfile Android Auto-Update

Tags: android, auto-update, passbook, wallet

I am currently working on a pkpass library for Android. There is one point that I cannot figure out. The [Apple's PassKit Web Service Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988) specifies how to register a device for automatic updates. This seems to work only with iOS devices.

However, there are a couple of apps out there for Android that are able to register for automatic updates somehow. [Wallet Passes | Passbook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.walletpasses.android) and [Pass2U Wallet for Passbook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.passesalliance.wallet) for instance.

I created a demo pkpass file using [PassSource's API](https://www.passsource.com/client/). When I update the file on their website, those apps get notified somehow and then show a notification to the user.

This is the behavior I'm trying to create but I cannot figure out for the life of me is what URL with which parameters to call.

I tried every possible combination of values for:

```
POST request to: webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber

Parameters

webServiceURL
The URL to your web service, as specified in the pass.
version
The protocol version—currently, v1.
deviceLibraryIdentifier
A unique identifier that is used to identify and authenticate this device in future requests.
passTypeIdentifier
The pass’s type, as specified in the pass.
serialNumber
The pass’s serial number, as specified in the pass.
Header

The Authorization header is supplied; its value is the word ApplePass, followed by a space, followed by the pass’s     authorization token as specified in the pass.

Payload

The POST payload is a JSON dictionary containing a single key and value:

pushToken
The push token that the server can use to send push notifications to this device.
```

as specified on the apple documentation.

I also studied [Walletpasses Documentation](https://walletpasses.io/developer/) and [Pass2U Documentation](https://www.pass2u.net/documentation)

Help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to create your own proprietary web service that mimics the Passbook WebService, then talk with pass issuers to forward device tokens and push requests to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not sure if I could get my question across... Other Apps like the ones I linked are capable of auto-update on Android. And Im sure they didn't all talk to every possible issuer of which there are potentially an infinite amount.

Comment: Actually, they did!  We are a major issuer and we explicitly added support for both of these platforms.  While they cannot possibly talk to every single issuer, they do publish their documentation on how to integrate.

Comment: Ok, so not the issuer has to integrate but the platform that offers the service of creating passbook files has?

Comment: Correct - although in many cases (E.g. corporations, airlines, etc.), these are one and the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just another reminder why apple sucks :/

Comment: What sucks is that Apple have not released a version of Wallet for Android.  But then, given the need for access to a Secure Element on the device, the need to provide apis for signature validation, and the need to support push messaging for Android devices globally (GCM is not available in China), then I can perfectly understand why not.  If they sucked so much, then why would you be building an app that replicates their software?

Comment: Simply because however much I dislike their business model it works and people use it. But that's another discussion ;) Also my client needs it and it's not intended to be a replication but an integration. I'm trying to get in touch with you via your website because maybe you can help us out here with your SDK.